# Open an image stored as BLOB in MySQL database

Tags: python, sql

I have stored an image as BLOB type in mysql database in phpmyadmin. I am using python code to interact with the database. So, how can I display the stored image from the database using SQL query?

Thanks.

Comment: what did you use to serialize the image?

Comment: I dint do anything. I just uploaded the image into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query part is just a matter of SELECTing the column containing the BLOB and storing it in a python variable. To display it, what we do in phpMyAdmin (PHP web application) is to send the proper headers for image type and then output the data from the variable.

For JPEG the correct header would be "Content-Type: image/jpeg". More details on http://codefellows.github.io/python-dev-accelerator/lectures/day07/http.html.

Comment: okay. Would you please help me with the proper code to display the image using the header? (if its a jpeg file)

Comment: I believe stackoverflow is there to help you with your existing code; please show us your existing code.